# How to go to a specific line in nano on macOS?

Tags: macos, keyboard, command-line, shortcut, monterey

nano shows the shortcut as `^/ Go To Line`.

It seems that `^` stands for the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on an Apple machine: the other shortcuts having it can be used with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>:

`^O Write Out      ^W Where Is       ^K Cut            ^T Execute` etc.

However, when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>, I get a system beep, as if the shortcut were invalid.

Same when pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> actually inserts `/`.

Specs:

- Machine: MacBook Pro, US physical keyboard and software layout
- OS: macOS Monterey 12.4

```
GNU nano, version 6.3  
 (C) 1999-2011, 2013-2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.  
 (C) 2014-2022 the contributors to nano  
 Compiled options: --disable-libmagic --enable-utf8
```

Bottom of the nano screen:

```
^G Help          ^O Write Out     ^W Where Is      ^K Cut           ^T Execute       ^C Location      M-U Undo         M-A Set Mark     M-] To Bracket   M-Q Previous     ^B Back          ^◂ Prev Word     ^A Home          ^P Prev Line
^X Exit          ^R Read File     ^\ Replace       ^U Paste         ^J Justify       ^/ Go To Line    M-E Redo         M-6 Copy         ^Q Where Was     M-W Next         ^F Forward       ^▸ Next Word     ^E End           ^N Next Line
```

Comment: ⌃ is Ctrl, not Cmd, which is ⌘. To complete the set,⌥ is Opt/alt. [I've no clue how that works in nano]

Comment: Where does nano show ^/ ? I see search as ^W Help is ^G note that ^ is the control key. Just tryed on nano in Monterey

Comment: @mmmmmm among the other shortcuts, at the bottom of the screen. I have added it to the question. You're right, `^` is `Ctrl,` even in nano. Correcting my question.

Comment: Your first line says  ^/ and the prompt says ^\ which is not the same thing

Comment: @mmmmmm I don't see it? I have mixed `Cmd` and `Ctrl` (now fixed). The issue is with the forward slash `/` and `Go to line`. I can use `Ctrl` + ```\``` (Replace) fine.

Comment: At the terminal what does `which nano` show as the "nano" in M<onterey is actually pico and does not have those keystrokes. How did you get the specs?

Comment: I did not know Monterey was actually using pico. I have installed it [with Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/nano.rb). It is aliased to `nano -c --linenumbers`.

Comment: OK I installed GNU nano and see the screen you get. ^/ Just works it prompts you for the line number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137202/discussion-between-pyb-and-mmmmmm).

Comment: WHich keyboard do you have?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer on StackOverflow: [jump to line X in nano editor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43350052/2223027)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> prompts `Enter line number, column number:`.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> works on GNU nano 7.2 :

```
 GNU nano, version 7.2
 (C) 2023 the Free Software Foundation and various contributors
 Compiled options: --disable-libmagic --enable-utf8
```

Comment: Ventura doesn't include GNU nano any longer, running nano starts pico.